# How to handle menu calls

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have been working on an app for a while and I designed a menu that when you press the 'menu' button in the navigation controller, it brings up the menu over top of whatever view you are currently on. When you press outside the menu it makes the menu dismiss itself and returns to just the view you were on previously. My problem is that when you press on the cells in the menu, I want it to dismiss the menu and then have the navigation controller on the super view pop to the new view (depending on which cell was pressed). Now I don't know if that is a really bad design or not. If this is possible I would love some feedback on where to get some more information on how to put that into action.

Here is an image of the menu in action running in the app:
[image: menu]

If this design for the menu is super complicated or not practical, a push in the right direction on how to implement one would be great. Have tried finding some resources but they are mostly pre-built menu's that you implement and I am not looking to use something like that. That is why I built my own!

Comment: "I want it to dismiss the menu and then have the navigation controller on the super view pop to the new view (depending on which cell was pressed)." So do that. What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: I have tried that previously and my issue was that it needs to dismiss itself first, then tell the navigation controller to pop to a new view but after it dismisses itself it doesn't do that. How do I pass the information back to the navigation controller on the super view

Comment: Your menu are essentially modal views that are auto dismissed  IOS has that kind of structure in iPad apps - which are the PopViewControllers - iPhone does not support  them but its is not hard to emulate by putting in a custom tap gesture for the mother view and an IBAction to dismiss the Pop if active.  - Come to think of it - it should also work for subviews/